# Vimperator: <C-v> is not passing through the key

Tags: keymapping, vimperator

is supposed to let keys pass though so that the consequent key press is recognized as if vimperator is not installed. I am getting a behavior that is equivalent to <kbd>p</kbd> of vimperator key, where the contents of the clipbaord is entered into the omnibar (or search bar). This seems like the default behavior as I have no mapping to  and there is no mention in the help page. How can I bring the pass through key back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try hitting 'i' or 'Insert' (ignore-keys feature).

Comment: Would you happen to know why <C-v> does not work anymore? (Since when?)

Comment: version3.1 revoked "PASSTHROUGH mode".  http://vimperator-labs.googlecode.com/hg/vimperator/NEWS